# Slow down a pulse (like 12hz / 3 to a 4hz output)

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, pulse

I am trying to output a slower pulse than is inputted into this mystery IC or circuit. This input pulse is digital and lasts for 1/10 of a second. Is there a chip that would allow me to proportionally slow down the speed of the input but a certain factor?

Comment: I used to use 74HC binary/decimal async/sync counters.

Comment: CD4060 with a pot

Comment: If you mean simply *decrease the frequency*, the comments above suffice. If you wish to *maintain the waveshape,* you'd need to record it, e.g., with an analog-to-digital converter, followed by a counter and digital-to-analog converter.

Comment: In the title you say 12Hz, but in the body you say it 'lasts for' 1/10 of a second. At 12Hz the period would be 1/12 of a second, so what is the **actual** frequency (12Hz, 10Hz, varying from ? to ?). What is the duty cycle or pulse width, and does either need to be preserved? What is this pulse coming from, and do you have _any_ idea what the 'mystery IC' does? Why do you want to slow it down?

Comment: Bruce Abbott, I am trying to slow down the pulse coming from a two-wire hall effect "switch" that is used as a cadence measuring device.

Comment: In this type of situation, it is often best if you can draw a diagram showing how the waveform is now, and how you want it to be. If you could draw a diagram like that and add it to your question, maybe it would keep the question from getting closed.

Comment: It's really super unclear what you want. What's the relation between input and output signal you want to maintain? I think mkeith is right, this is a situation where it's hard for you to put your requirements into sufficiently precise words to make us understand, so let a drawing be your language – but make sure you label axes (precisely), and clearly annotate what you want to cause what (e.g. with labeled arrows or something). As it is, I'm reading your question, and simply have *no clue* what you want, and I'm not alone...

Comment: As I understand you, you want a pulse width multiplier. So in receiving a digital input pulse oft a given length, output a pulse of a certain multiple of the input length. Do you have a specification on the maximum pulse width you need to handle? What should happen if a new pulse arrives while the stretched pulse is still active on the output? Given answers to these two questions, we can likely suggest appropriate solutions for your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ICs that produce a digital pulse train whose frequency is some integer division of the input signal's frequency. They are called "divide by N counters". Check these out:

1. [CD4018](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/270/108781_DS.pdf) (3V - 15V supply)
2. [CD4059](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4059a.pdf) (3V - 15V supply)
3. [74HC4059](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/h9vgntlilh/TXII-S-A0001069381-1.pdf) (2V - 6V supply)

You could also use a "rate multiplier" IC, which create fractional output frequencies such as \$ f_{IN} \times \frac{N}{64} \$. Here are a couple:

1. [CD4089](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4089b.pdf) (3V - 15V supply)
2. [7497](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn5497.pdf) (5V only, ancient TTL device, not recommended)